# form-checkbox css of bootstrap3 equivalent in bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using `<input type="checkbox class="form-checkbox form-control-radio">` in bootstrap 3.
I am trying to upgrade to bootstrap 4 , not able to find these classes **form-checkbox form-control-radio** .

Are these classes removed or do we have any equivalent of it in bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap v3 are no longer maintain by bootstrap team so you can use this.
`class="form-checkbox form-control-radio"` In bootstrap v4 those class are removed by the bootstrap team, so those class are no longer work so you can't be use them. for your solutions you can use these class..

````
    <div class="input-group-text">
      <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input">
    </div>
  </div>```

to checked box. for more details you can follow bootstrap v4 official document.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#multiple-inputs
````

Answer (score 1):

Yes, This classes are removed from the bootstrap

You can use below classes for bootstrap 4

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
</div>
```

For more information you can refer this link of bootstrap a
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/